# File.listFiles will only list files with dot extension

Tags: java

The typical file lists just fine.

myfile.txt

returns as expected.

myfile

without an extension does not return a file object.

Windows 7, Java JDK6 - Updating is not an option :(

Interestingly extensionless files do not show up as directories either.

```
File dir = new File("c:/somedirectory/");
File[] returnFiles = dir.listFiles();
```

Added code as requested.  Expect 2 files in array and get one.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Elaborate more about this "without an extension does not return a file object." where are you trying put a file name without an extension?

Comment: If you try `new File("c:/somedirectory/", "myfile");`, does that file exist? Do you have both `myfile.txt` and `myfile` in the directory?

Comment: The files I'm receiving from an outside source come in with no file extension.  They are specially formatted character delimited files.  The entity providing them felt no need to add an extension.  Just thought it was weird.  I can work in the transfer process to add an extension.  Thought it worth asking.

Comment: I have both     myfile.txt and     myfile in the directory

Comment: try this to check 'myfile' is a file or not  ->                     for (File file : fList) {
          
             if (file.isFile()) { //do somthing }

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this error using Java 1.8.0_73. Both `myfile.txt` and `myfile` were listed during the test.

Comment: Might be a Java 6 thing.  Also isfile() will not trigger due to the array being empty of the file i'm after.

Comment: @Call_Back_Function `array being empty` so is anything being returned? Also, I doubt much changed from Java 6 to 8 in `java.io`. Maybe its your JVM, what vendor are you using?

Comment: Oracle JDK 6.  With those two files in the directory I'm just getting the one back in the array.  I'll test on another machine and see if I get a different result.  Thanks for rubber ducking.

Comment: `File.listFiles()` does not and has never worked the way you have described, in any Java release since it was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

I took the reference of the Java 6 documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html). There aren't many changes for the class File from java 6 to java 8.

So I have executed a small sample of code with Java 7 and Java 8 on Unix.

```
    File dir = new File("/Users/somedirectory");
    File[] returnFiles = dir.listFiles();
    String[] files = dir.list();

    for(File f:returnFiles ){
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }

    for(String f:files ){
        System.out.println(f);
    }
```

My observation is that the first loop returned all the files including the hidden files along with both normal files and extensionless files. While the second one returned labels/names of all files and directories.

So I assume that the extensionless file may have been considered as directory instead of as file for some reason.